# AngularJS and Spring MVC Project remove '#!'

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I'm working on a project Using AngularJS as front-end and Spring MVC as back-end. Also I used plugin `ui-router`. The base url looks like `localhost:8080/PROJECT_NAME/#!` For a better looking I'm trying to remove the `/#!/` from url.

I failed to get a correct result from the common solution from internet:

```
// Insert this into Angularjs module config file
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

// Add this into META tag
<base href="/">
```

After doing this what I got is all resources crashed, so I added my project name:

```
<base href="PROJECT_NAME">
```

Resources are correctly fetched, however, the log shows:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:

(anonymous function)    @   angular.js:68
(anonymous function)    @   angular.js:4756
forEach @   angular.js:357
loadModules @   angular.js:4717
createInjector  @   angular.js:4639
doBootstrap @   angular.js:1838
angular.resumeBootstrap @   angular.js:1867
maybeBootstrap  @   hint.js:569
```

I don't know what to do next, may need your help, thanks!

---

Router code:

```
app.config(
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

        $stateProvider
            .state('index', {
                url: "/",
                templateUrl: "homeview"
            });

        // use the HTML5 History API
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }
);
```

Comment: post your routing code? (maybe app.js)

Comment: Hi @Nagaveer Gowda I've posted on tail of my question body, it's quite standard. I supported that templateURL from spring MVC controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[1] Set html5Mode as true using below mentioned code,

```
.config(["$locationProvider", function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}])
```

[2] Set base url in index.html as follows,

```
<base href="/" />
```

[3] Create a controller to redirect urls to the index file

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{[path:[^\\.]*}")
public String stalklist() {
    return "forward:/";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That `#` notifies the AngularJS that there is no need to go to the server for that url instead go to `ng-router`.

So ideally you should not remove that.

Answer (score 0):

use the **$locationProvider** module and set **html5Mode** to *true*.

```
angular.module('StudentView', []).
 config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

$routeProvider.
  when('/student', {templateUrl: 'partials/studentList.html',   controller: StudentListCtrl}).
  when('/student/:studentId', {templateUrl: 'partials/studentDetail.html', controller: StudentDetailCtrl}).
  otherwise({redirectTo: '/phones'});

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  }]);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I did, however, it looks like it goto the server instead of angular, and returned me 404.